# Java 8 Stream() With Complex condition for List and it should return one result

Tags: java, filter, collections, java-8, java-stream

I have list of phone numbers and I need to filter based on the type of phone. End result should be single object(PhoneUsageType). 
Example scenario
1. If list has 2 different types of phone numbers like Cell_Phone and Home_Phone the it should return me only Cell_Phone object. 
2.If it has only Cell_Phone then directly it should return me that object
3.If it has it does'nt have Cell_Phone then it should return me Home_Phone

Cell_Phone should be preferred object if its available in the list

Using **list.stream().filter**

Code

```
PhoneUsageType phone1 = new PhoneUsageType();
PhoneUsageKeyGrpType keyGroup1 = new PhoneUsageKeyGrpType();
keyGroup1.setPurposeCode("CELL_PHONE");
phone1.setPhoneUsageKeyGrp(keyGroup1);
PhoneNumberType phoneNumber1 = new PhoneNumberType();
phoneNumber1.setFullNumber("123");
phone1.setPhoneNumber(phoneNumber1);

PhoneUsageType phone2 = new PhoneUsageType();
PhoneUsageKeyGrpType keyGroup2 = new PhoneUsageKeyGrpType();
keyGroup2.setPurposeCode("CELL_PHONE");
phone2.setPhoneUsageKeyGrp(keyGroup2);
PhoneNumberType phoneNumber2 = new PhoneNumberType();
phoneNumber2.setFullNumber("456");
phone2.setPhoneNumber(phoneNumber2);

List<PhoneUsageType> phoneUsageList = Lists.newArrayList();
```

Please help me to write the logic. Thanks in advance. Let me know if you need more details.

Comment: you should include class PhoneUsageType to your question

Comment: You didn't mention the expected output or the attempt that you've already made.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use `filter`, use `min` or `max` sorting by type.

Something like the following:

```
enum PhoneType {
    CELL, WORK, HOME; // in order of preference
}

class Phone {
    public PhoneType getType() ...
    public String getNumber() ...
}

Phone best = Collections.min(phoneList, Comparator.comparing(Phone::getType));
```

Comment: Or `Phone best = Collections.min(phoneList, preferredNumber);`

Answer (score 1):

Better use min and max sorting types

```
enum PhoneType {
    Mobile, Office, personal; // in order of preference
}

class Mobile {
    public PhoneType getType() 
    public String getNumber() 
}

Comparator<Mobile> preferredNumber = Comparator.comparing(Mobile::getType);

Mobile best = mobileList.stream().min(preferredNumber).orElseThrow();
```

Hope you get it.